# O que é e para quê serve o XPath fornecido nas ferramentas de desenvolvedor do navegador?

Tags: html, xpath

Ao abrir as Ferramentas do Desenvolvedor no Chrome para copiar o HTML de um elemento `<div id="teste">`, vi que existe uma opção "*copy XPath*" conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao escolher essa opção, ele manda pra área de transferência o seguinte:

```
//*[@id="teste"]
```

O que eu gostaria de conhecer é o quê seria essa informação e como eu poderia usá-la.

Comment: https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html acho que isso pode te interessar e isso aqui tb direto da W3C https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Segundo a [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) (em livre tradução):

> XPath (XML Path Language) é uma linguagem de consulta para selecionar nós de um documento XML . Além disso, o XPath pode ser usado para calcular valores (por exemplo, strings , números ou valores booleanos ) do conteúdo de um documento XML. O XPath foi definido pelo World Wide Web Consortium (W3C)

XPath usa expressões de caminho para selecionar um "nó" ou um conjunto de "nós" em um documento XML ou HTML.

**O que você recebeu ao executar a função `Copy XPath` foi uma "expressão de caminho"** que representa um "caminho" segundo a sintaxe XPath para o "nó" no documento com o atributo `id` igual a **"teste"** sendo as duas "barras" a indicação que a consulta parte/inicia na raiz do documento e o asterisco (wildcard) para buscar tudo, as opções (parâmetros) entre os colchetes são usadas para filtrar a consulta.

Em javascript sua interface principal utiliza [`Document.evaluate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate) que recebe cinco parâmetros:

```
document.evaluate( xpathExpression, contextNode, namespaceResolver, resultType, result )
```

- **xpathExpression**: expressão XPath (expressões de caminho)
- **contextNode**: um "nó" no documento para ser avaliado
- **namespaceResolver**: função para prefixos de namespace (HTML não possui namespaces)
- **resultType**: uma constante que especifica o tipo de resultado desejado
- **result**: objeto XPathResult

As "expressões de caminho" usadas por XPath pode ser absolutas representadas pela "barra" `/` ou relativas (nodeName, //, .,.., @, entre outras).

O contextNode pode ser um "nó" no documento ou o próprio `document` caso se deseje uma consulta "global".

Como mencionado HTML não possui "namespaces" por isto ao analisar documentos HTML o terceiro parâmetro deve receber um valor `null`.

Os três tipos principais resultType são:

> **iteradores**

- **UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE**
- **ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE**

Um conjunto de "nós" que podem ser iterados individualmente usando `iterateNext()` sobre o object (XPathResult). Caso o documento seja modificado durante uma iteração a execção `NS_ERROR_DOM_INVALID_STATE_ERR` será lançada.

> **instantâneos**

- **UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE**
- **ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE**

Um conjunto de "nós" estáticos, os snapshots não mudam com as mutações do documento, por isto não lançam exceções caso o "nó" tenha mudado no documento ou mesmo se tenha sido removido durante a iteração.

> **primeiros nós**

- **ANY_UNORDERED_NODE_TYPE**
- **FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE**

Retorna o primeiro nó encontrado que correspondeu à expressão XPath.

A constante `ANY_TYPE` retorna-rá qualquer tipo que naturalmente resulte da avaliação da expressão. Pode ser qualquer um dos tipos simples (NUMBER_TYPE, STRING_TYPE, BOOLEAN_TYPE), más, se o tipo de resultado retornado for um conjunto de "nós", ele será apenas um `UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE`.

Estas constantes são definidas pelo objecto `XPathResult` e a lista completa de tipos pode ser encontrada no apêndice desta documentação: [Mozila Developer - XPath in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript#XPathResult_Defined_Constants)

Já o resultado (result) pode ser um objeto `XPathResult` ou `null`(que criará um novo objeto XPathResult)

XPath possui um conjunto de funções que podem ser observadas aqui: [Mozila Developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions)

Um exemplo básico para buscar e contar todos os elementos `<p>` no documento:

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('count')

btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    let paragraphCount = document.evaluate( 'count(//p)', document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null )
    alert( 'Este documento contém ' + paragraphCount.numberValue + ' elementos de paragrafo')
}, false)
```

```html
<p>Paragraph one</p>
<p>Paragraph two</p>
<p>Paragraph tree</p>
<p>...</p>

<br>

<button id="count" type="button">contar</button>
```

As expressões de caminho podem usar [`"eixos"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes) que complementam a query de consulta, estes "eixos" devem sempre estar envoltos em colchetes, exemplo:

- **`//aside[@lang='en']`**: seleciona todos os elementos `<aside>` que têm um atributo "lang" com um valor "en"
- **`/footer/div[last()]`**: seleciona o último elemento `<div>` que é o filho do elemento `<footer>`
- **`/nav/button[1]`**: seleciona o primeiro elemento `<button>` que é o filho do elemento `<nav>`

Estas expressões também aceitam [`"operadores"`](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_operators.asp) assim como "curingas" `*` de modo a tornar a consulta mais construtiva.

---

> Opinião (caso de uso)

Usei há algum tempo atrás esta sintaxe para buscar com `XMLHttpRequest()` fragmentos de HTML que seriam acomodados ao DOM programaticamente más, confesso ser difícil manter a organização. Mudei de foco e passei para uma abordagem usando `fetch()` e `.text()` da resposta e manipular os fragmentos usando uma função especifica que criei.

No HTML uma vez que ela retorna "nós" pode ser útil para construir analisadores ou manipuladores de objetos, sua gama potencial de uso depende da proposta (necessidade) e da criatividade do desenvolvedor.

Para mim (minha critica) é só mais uma forma de atravessar documento.

Já no XML é fácil observar seu potencial, exemplo:

```js
fetch('https://subversivo58.github.io/lab/assets/XPath-example.xml').then(r => {
    if ( r.ok ) {
        return r.text()
    }
    throw new Error('Failed request XML Document! Status code: ' + r.status)
}).then(text => {
    showResult((new window.DOMParser()).parseFromString(text, "text/xml"))
}).catch(e => {
    console.error(e)
})


function showResult(xml) {
    var txt = "";
    path = "/bookstore/book/title"
    if ( xml.evaluate ) {
        var nodes = xml.evaluate(path, xml, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
        var result = nodes.iterateNext();
        while (result) {
            txt += result.childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";
            result = nodes.iterateNext();
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>

<br>

<p>Este código foi baseado nesta <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=try_xpath_select_cdnodes" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">fonte</a></p>
```

---

> Links e documentações:

Supporte a `document.evaluate` e `XPath` [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=document-evaluate-xpath)

[image: xpath]

- **XPath Wikipedia**: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath)
- **XPath 3.1**: [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-3/)
- **XPath Syntax**: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms256471(v=vs.110).aspx)
- **XPath**: [Mozila Developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath)
- **XPath Operators**: [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_operators.asp), [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms256074(v=vs.110).aspx)
- **XPath XML examples**: [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_examples.asp)

---

**PS**:

Fontes como Mozila Deleveloper, W3Schools ou MSDN carecem de apresentar nas suas documentações todas as referencias a funções, operadores ou mesmo a sintaxe usada em XPath.

Comment: Há alguma vantagem em utilizar o `document.evaluate` em vez de `document.querySelectorAll` ou `document.querySelector`?

Comment: Propriamente dito `querySelector()` ou `querySelectorAll()` são seletores de `CSS` já `XPath` é próprio para `DOM` (seletor de nós) ... eu mesmo já não uso mais e nunca fiz questão de testar mas depois de seu comentário fiz uma breve pesquisa e encontrei este teste em [jsperf.com](https://jsperf.com/xpath-vs-queryselectorall). Parece que `XPath` é mais rápido que `querySelectorAll()`

Comment: Só uma coisa, testes no front-end nunca são precisos... devem levar em consideração que irão gerar resultados diferentes para cada navegador bem como a própria base de quem esta "testando" (arquitetura do sistema, processador, memoria, etc...)

Answer (score 5):

Resumidamente `Xpath` é uma linguagem de busca de nós em documentos `XML` (mas também utilizada em `HTML`), você executa uma expressão Xpath em um certo documento XML/HTML/ qualquerMLsuportado e o resultado vai ser 0 ou mais nós que equivalem aquela expressão.

É muito similar a `seletores CSS`. Por exemplo podemos escrever as duas buscas equivalentes em CSS e Xpath: `div > .className p` em css e `//div/[contains(@class, 'className')//p` em xpath, ambas representam "todos os elementos `p` descendentes diretos ou indiretos de elementos com a classe `className`, sendo esses por sua vez filhos diretos de `div`".

Embora quase idênticos em propósito a seletores CSS, seletores Xpath são mais poderosos. Tem uma infinidade de buscas que são possíveis em Xpath mas não em CSS, alguns exemplos de simples demonstração:

- buscar nós ancenstrais `//div/..` (todos os parents de divs);
- buscar nós de acordo com regra `>` em atributo `//section[valor>35.00]` (sections com atributo valor maior que 35.00);
- buscar elemetos cujo texto interno seja equivalente `//p[text()=../blockquote/text()]` (todos os `p` cujo parent possua um filho `blockquote` com texto igual a `p`).

Logo Xpath é muito útil em casos onde:

1. seja a única coisa disponível (derp);
2. você precisa fazer buscas complexas que não possam ser expressadas em outra linguagem de busca disponível (css por exemplo).

Um caso de uso muito comum é no [selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/), uma ferrameta de automatização de ações em navegadores, basicamente você escreve código que imita ações de usuários no navegador para testar interfaces de forma automatizada. É possível usar CSS e Xpath (a API vai variar conforme a linguagem), geralmente é preferível CSS pela legibilidade e simplicidade, mas as vezes você  quer expressar algo do tipo "atributo `value` do `input#id` tem o mesmo valor que o contido na `textarea#id`" e aí não tem muitas opções fora Xpath.

Obs: recomendo [este post](https://johnresig.com/blog/xpath-css-selectors/) do John Resig (criador da `jQuery`) sobre uma comparação de Xpath vs CSS.